Calculating the differential equation for a 1 capacitor 2 resistor high pass filter
First time posting here so I hope I'm doing everything right. I need to calculate the differential equation for a high pass filter as seen in the schematic where R1 = 3R, R2 = R and C1 = C. I know how to calculate the differential equation of a high pass filter, but I am completely stuck on this. Can anyone help me out here?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

You say you know the high-pass filter, but you show a high-pass filter. What seems to be the problem? Show your work: what are the component equations? Node equations? What step are you stuck on?

@tim-williams I meant I know how to do it for a first order passive high pass filter. I know that the voltage across the whole circuit has to be 0, so $ U_C + U_R + U_2 - U_1 = 0 $ ($ U_1 $ is $ U_{in} $ and $ U_2 $ is $ U_{out} $), also that the current at the node has to be 0, so $ I_C + I_R = I_{3R} $. $ I_C = C dU_C/dt $. $ I_R = U_R/R $ and $ I_3R = U_2/3R $. So I get as far as $ RC \dot{U}_C + U_R = 1/3 U_2 $, but now I don't know how to rewrite $ U_R $ and $ U_C $ so that I am left with only $ U_1 $ and $ U_2 $ in the final equation.

I meant $ I_{3R} = U_2/3R $

@BenBockhoff I just saw this. Do I take it that you are not looking for the Laplace transfer function for vout/vin. But the differential solution equation in the time domain? Because they are quite related. Is the initial condition of the capacitor known or specified or assumed zero at t=0?

@BenBockhoff Clue: Solve $\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{C_1\left(R_1+R_2\right)}\right)V_{\text{OUT}}=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V{_\text{IN}}$.

@periblepsis all information I have is to solve the differential equation for the given circuit and then derive the time constant $ \tau $ and the transfer function. I'll try and work with your clue, thank you.

@BenBockhoff If you just inspect the equation I show above, you can find the time constant there. It sticks out. The transfer function is just the Laplace form, which you can also get from the above equation by simple re-arrangement to solve for Vout/Vin. Then replace all the differential operators with s. Done. You can also look here for some more work product that may be of some small use. And here for a note about one relationship between Laplace and time domain annihilation.

@periblepsis I tried solving it on my own again and I get to the same solution that your clue gives me with $ 4RC \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}V_{out} + V_{out} = 3RC\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}V_{in} $ but I can't figure out how to derive $ \tau $ from that... Edit: I just saw your new comment. Give me a few minutes to look at that, thank you

@BenB Anytime you see any annihilator of the form $\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right)$, you know that the solution is always of the form $A\exp\left(\alpha,t\right)$. Since $\alpha,t$ must be unitless, it's clear that $\alpha$ is a frequency, not time. So $\frac1{\alpha}$ would have the units of time. You can see from my example then that $\tau_{_0}=4,R,C$. It's that simple.

@BenB Set gain $A=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}=\frac34$ and critical frequency $\omega_{0}=\frac{1}{C_1\left(R_1+R_2\right)}=\frac{1}{4,R,C}$, then re-arrange the equation I gave earlier to find $\frac{V{\text{OUT}}}{V{\text{IN}}}=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\cdot\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{C_1\left(R_1+R_2\right)}}=A\frac{s}{s+\omega{0}}$. Clearly, $\tau{0}=\frac1{\omega{_0}}=4,R,C$.

@periblepsis I wanna say the time constant looks to be $ \tau = 4RC $ because you said it sticks out and I know the time constant is $ \tau = RC $ for a passive first order high pass filter but the fact that $ V_{in} $ is a derivative here is throwing me a bit off. If I do what you said for the transfer function I get $ \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{3}{4} + 3RCs $. Does that look right at least?

@periblepsis I saw your new comments. You were a little too quick for me haha. I think with your explanation I got it now. I'm a physics student and this electrical engineering stuff is a bit hard for me I don't know. Clearly it's not that difficult but oh well. Thanks a lot! You're saving my exam preperations.

@BenB Do you know how to apply KCL to find such a simple solution? It doesn't seem so. But... Do you need to see how?

@periblepsis I know KCL but maybe I am missing something here? I think this should've been way simpler than I made it out to be so I probably am.

@periblepsis so I just applied KCL to the start conditions and I know now how you got to $ \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{1}{4RC} \right) V_{out} = \frac{3}{4} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} V_{in} $. I just have to remember how to extract the time constant and transfer function from that but you explained that pretty well

@BenB Note that if Vin is a constant voltage then the right side is just zero and the equation is already homogeneous. Easy to solve for Vout. If Vin is some other function (say an exponential or a sinusoidal form) then you need to add an annihilator to both sides, where the annihilator is "designed" to kill Vin. That makes it homogeneous, again. But you will have more factors on the left, each of which will have separate solution equations that are added together.

You can use a set of KCL equations from your schematic:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The KCL is:
# method 1, solve each node individually:
eqv1 = Eq( v1*s*c1 + v1/r2, vin*s*c1 + vout/r2)
eqvout = Eq( vout/r1 + vout/r2, v1/r2 )
ans = solve( [eqv1, eqvout], [v1, vout] )
simplify( ans[vout]/vin )
c1*r1*s/(c1*r1*s + c1*r2*s + 1)
#
# method 2, combine C1 and R2 into a single impedance and solve:
simplify( solve( Eq( vout/r1 + vout/(r2+1/s/c1), vin/(r2+1/s/c1) ), vout )[0]/vin )
c1*r1*s/(c1*r1*s + c1*r2*s + 1)

Same answer either way. Just using KCL.
Neither of the above is in standard form, though. You should expect the order of s in the numerator to be equal to or less than the order found in the denominator. In this case, the order is equal and it is a high-pass.
The next thing to do is to ensure that the highest order s term in the denominator has a factor of 1, only. Or, alternately, ensure that the lowest order s term (\$s^0\$) is just one. These are the two different, but equivalent, standard ways of writing a high-pass or low-pass. (A band-pass has a 3rd way of writing it in standard form.) So you need to divide the denominator (and numerator) by \$C_1\left(R_1+R_2\right)\$.
The standard form will have a gain (which is the gain for a low-pass at DC and is the gain for a high-pass at infinity) and then the rest of the transfer function in fractional form.
$$\begin{align*}\require{cancel}
\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}&=\frac{R_1\,C_1\,s}{R_1\,C_1\,s + R_2\,C_1\,s + 1}
\\\\
&=\frac{R_1\,C_1\,s}{C_1\left(R_1 + R_2\right)s + 1}
\\\\
&=\frac{\frac{R_1\,\cancel{C_1}\,s}{\cancel{C_1}\left(R_1 + R_2\right)}}{\frac{\cancel{C_1\left(R_1 + R_2\right)}}{\cancel{C_1\left(R_1 + R_2\right)}}s + \frac1{C_1\left(R_1 + R_2\right)}}
\\\\
&=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\cdot\frac{s}{s+\frac1{C_1\left(R_1 + R_2\right)}}
\end{align*}$$
With \$A\$ as the gain, then as \$s\to\infty\$ it follows that \$A\to\frac34\$. So it's just \$A=\frac34\$. The critical frequency \$\omega_{_0}=\frac{1}{C_1\left(R_1+R_2\right)}\$ and \$\tau_{_0}=\frac1{\omega_{_0}}=4\,R\,C\$.
An alternate standard form would be: \$\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}=A\frac{\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}}{\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}+1}\$.
